# GTK+ Forth callbacks

Tags: callback, gtk, signals, forth

I recently came across an article of Manfred Mahlow from four years back which came close to solving a problem I am having.  The article, "Using Glade to Create GTK+ Applications in Forth" touched upon signal handlers, stating that Forth could not be used, but only C to create them.  I think my problem remains a small one, but I am stumped, I wold be very appreciative of any suggestions.  Secondarily, if anyone knows how to send an email to Mr.  Mahlow without using a dash in the address, I would love to hear it.

I am writing an application using the Linux version of [SwiftForth](http://www.forth.com/swiftforth/index.html) to create a custom window and receive keypresses and write to that window. My goal is to implement Charles Moore's [colorForth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColorForth), enhanced and more user friendly. I decided to use [GTK+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B), knowing little about it, but I have been successful but for the callbacks (signal handlers). There are only two pages of code in the whole thing, so I put it here:

```
\ ------------------------ COLOR FORTH -----------------------

ANEW TASK-COLORFORTH

LIBRARY  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.1000.8

FUNCTION: gtk_window_new ( code -- addr )
FUNCTION: gtk_widget_destroy ( wptr -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_window_close ( wptr -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_widget_show  ( wptr -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_init  ( -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_window_set_decorated ( wptr flag -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_window_move  ( wptr x y -- )
\ FUNCTION: gtk_widget_new  ( n addr -- )  ( try 0 0 )
\ FUNCTION: gtk_widget_map  ( wptr -- )
\ FUNCTION: gtk_widget_show_all  ( wptr -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_window_get_screen  ( wptr -- wgptr )
\ FUNCTION: gtk_window_present  ( wptr -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_window_set_title ( wptr TitlePtr -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_window_resize ( wptr width height -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_widget_modify_bg ( wptr state cptr -- )
\ FUNCTION: gtk_widget_modify_fg ( wptr state cptr -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_widget_modify_text ( wptr state cptr -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_widget_modify_base ( wptr statre cptr -- )
FUNCTION: g_signal_connect_data ( wptr name callback data 0 0 -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_main ( -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_main_quit ( -- )
FUNCTION: gtk_widget_set_events ( wptr flag -- )

LIBRARY  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0.1000.8
FUNCTION: gdk_event_get_keyval ( eptr kptr -- )
FUNCTION: gdk_event_get_state ( eptr sptr -- )
FUNCTION: gdk_event_get_event_type ( eptr -- type ) ( requires GET.RETURN )

\ LIBRARY  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.4000.0
\ LIBRARY /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4000.0
\ LIBRARY /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0.3600.3
\ LIBRARY /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0.21009.1
\ LIBRARY /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4000.0
\ LIBRARY /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3000.7

VARIABLE Window-Ptr
VARIABLE Event-Ptr
VARIABLE KeyVal
VARIABLE KeyState

Z" ColorForth"         VALUE Title
Z" key_press_event"    VALUE Keypress-Name
Z" delete_event"       VALUE Delete-Event-Name
Z" destroy"            VALUE Destroy-Name

CREATE Background 0 , 0 H, 0 H, $2000 H,
CREATE Black 0 , 0 H, 0 H, 0 H,
CREATE White 0 , $E000 H, $E000 H, $8000 H,

\ ----------------------------------------------------------------

ICODE LEAVE.FALSE
    EAX EAX SUB
    RET
END-CODE

ICODE GET.RETURN
    4 # EBP SUB
    EBX 0 [EBP] MOV
    EAX EBX MOV
    RET
END-CODE

         \  This may be the part where I am having problems

: SHUTDOWN
    Window-Ptr @   DUP  gtk_window_close
    gtk_widget_destroy
;

: CB.DELETE.EVENT ( wptr data -- false to destroy )
    RDROP RDROP             ( assuming 2 paramaters on Rstack and return -1 )
    LEAVE.FALSE
;

: CB.DESTROY     ( wptr data -- )
    RDROP RDROP                        ( two parameters here )
    gtk_main_quit
;

: CB.KEYPRESS   ( wptr eptr data -- )     ( assuming 3 parameters on Rstack )
    Window-Ptr @ .  R> . R> . R> .   R@   (  This for diagnosis – eventually )
    SHUTDOWN                              ( goes to a [SWITCH )
;

: STARTUP   ( -- )
    Window-Ptr OFF  Event-Ptr OFF
    gtk_init
    0 gtk_window_new ?DUP    ( 0 = GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL )
      IF DUP Window-Ptr !
         DUP 1024 gtk_widget_set_events       ( 1024 for Keypress signals )
         DUP Title gtk_window_set_title
         DUP 1280 850 gtk_window_resize
         DUP 0 gtk_window_set_decorated
         DUP 0 Background gtk_widget_modify_bg
         DUP Delete-Event-Name  [ ' CB.DELETE.EVENT +ORIGIN ] LITERAL  0
           0 0  g_signal_connect_data
         DUP Destroy-Name  [ ' CB.DESTROY +ORIGIN ] LITERAL 0
           0 0  g_signal_connect_data
         DUP Keypress-Name  [ ' CB.KEYPRESS +ORIGIN ] LITERAL 0
           0 0  g_signal_connect_data
         gtk_widget_show
      THEN
      gtk_main
;
```

I could not use the usual g_signal_connect because I could not find it in any library I have. If it turns up, I would use it since the code is simpler. However, this code above compiles, and when I type STARTUP, it does just that. The window is there as I have specified, the signals are set, but pressing any key crashes SwiftForth with a "segmentation fault".

As you see, I am feeding the absolute address of the handler to the signal connect function. I have also tried to put that address into a variable and handing it as a pointer, but this yields a GTK+ error.

In writing the handlers I assumed that it would operate like any library call. The input parameters would be on the return stack, supplied by GTK as the handler code executes, and I am supposed to put any returns into EAX. But this analysis could be wrong. I may be preparing the address wrong or handler"s parameters wrong, or have totally the wrong concept.

I am hoping that, despite the statement that handlers would have to be in C, there is some way to simulate what the C code would do, in assembler if necessary.

I sense that I am one hurdle away from making this breakthrough, and if anyone could send a few suggestions or places where I might look, I would be very grateful.

Comment: If I were you, I would try to boil down the problem to a minimum number of lines.  Maybe just the callback, gtk_init, gtk_window_new and a call to g_signal_connect_data.  Also, do the same in C and analyse the disassembly.

Comment: You did not find `g_signal_connect` because it is a [C macro](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gobject/gsignal.h#n458). The real handler is [`g_signal_connect_data`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gobject/gsignal.c#n2367).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FUNCTION: g_signal_connect_data ( wptr name callback data 0 0 -- )`
I see you're using things like `' CB.DELETE.EVENT +ORIGIN` to pass as
the callback parameter.

Shouldn't you use a Forth callback to begin with? Your
`CB.DELETE.EVENT` (and the others) needs and expects a Forth
context.

In SwiftForth this can be achieved with

```
' CB.DELETE.EVENT 2 CB: *CB.DELETE>EVENT
```

Pass `*CB.DELETE>EVENT` as the callback parameter to `g_signal_connect_data`

`CB:` creates a wrapper around `CB.DELETE.EVENT` which establishes a
temporary Forth environment to run in. See the SwiftForth manual
for accessing the parameters given to callbacks. Of course the
other callbacks should be adapted likewise.

Note: SwiftForth deals with the inputs in a specific way. Other
Forth systems differ in how they handle the callback input
parameters. But in general it's good not to depend blindly on
the return stack. Always check the Forth documentation.

While the import-library words facilitate non-Forth functions to
run in a Forth environment, the reverse, running Forth words in
a foreign context, is done with the callback words. They allow
for signal handlers, completion handlers, exception handlers,
start routine for POSIX threads, method implementations for Objective-C
classes, etc., etc. Many Forth systems running under an OS like
SwiftForth, VFX, iForth, MacForth, iMops and Gforth provide ways
to create Forth callbacks. So any claim Forth can't be used here
is refuted I guess. See [this Forth + GTK example](http://www.mpeforth.com/vfxlinux.htm#gtk).

BTW, I ran the adapted code in SwiftForth OS X. OK ;-)

Comment: I appreciate your amended comments.